# 2 Duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm having an error in react native ios using xcode 12. I installed **react-native-sensors** and **react-native-share**, it seems like they have the same classes. Here's the error.

```
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_Utils' in:
    /Users/Fennecteck/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/runm8-aupqcfeohtwloyeyhjaowldkxzbn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNSensors/libRNSensors.a(Utils.o)
    /Users/Fennecteck/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/runm8-aupqcfeohtwloyeyhjaowldkxzbn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNShare/libRNShare.a(Utils.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_Utils' in:
    /Users/Fennecteck/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/runm8-aupqcfeohtwloyeyhjaowldkxzbn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNSensors/libRNSensors.a(Utils.o)
    /Users/Fennecteck/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/runm8-aupqcfeohtwloyeyhjaowldkxzbn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RNShare/libRNShare.a(Utils.o)
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried **'No Common Blocks' from Yes to No** but still having this error. Also removing the **-ObjC**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is conflict of 2 classes in this packages. Latest class was created in react-native-share (https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share/compare/v4.0.4...v4.1.0)

I have a same issue and to resolve it I created an issue in repository (https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share/issues/913).

To fix it now, better solution is to downgrade version of package, who was latest created this duplicated class

- react-native-share from 4.1.0 to 4.0.4 (this is worked for me)

Comment: May i know what is the version of your react-native-sensors? thank you.

Comment: @carch yep, latest version at the moment of commenting (and still) - 7.0.2